# Бесконечная работа бота [PHP]

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Пишу бота по vk api для личных сообщений. Хотелось бы узнать как можно сделать бесконечную работу бота. Сейчас все идет через цикл `while`, но он же не может работать вечно. Cron не вариант. Как найти выход?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под бесконечной работой? Приведите код и поясните, что именно вы хотите.

Comment: @Pyramidhead Да собственно чего там приводить то, `file_get_contents` к API и т.д. А под бесконечной работой, я имею ввиду, что она не будет обрываться, например хостер может не давать вечно работать циклу.

Comment: php-скрипты не должны работать бесконечно. Грубо говоря, они нужны лишь для того, чтобы обработать какие-то данные и вывести результат.

Comment: @Pyramidhead Можете в таком случает посоветовать язык для написания такого "вечно работающего" бота?

Comment: Вариантов масса, только для таких вещей нужен VPS/VDS. Если бы вы привели код и подробнее описали свою задачу, можно было бы конкретнее ответить на вопрос. Быть может, там и не нужен бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Вообще все зависит только от хостера. ограничений с точки зрения используемого языка, сделать php скрипт с вечным циклом нет никаких. Первоначальный запуск скрипта в этом случае должен быть размещен в скриптах загрузки системы или в cron, с указанием что его так же надо выполнять разово, при старте системы. Конечно некоторые хостеры могут ограничивать время работы скриптов, но тогда они скорее всего ограничивают и работу скриптов на любых других языках, просто выбирайте хостера, который этого не делает

Answer (score 1):

Для подобных целей стоит использовать node js.

Comment: Спасибо за совет